# Backbone.Marrionette Trigger

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm looking to bubble up an event from an `ItemView` to the respective controller using `Backbone.Marionettes'` message bus, via the built in `Trigger` method.

Below, the triggers method is listening to the proper `jQuery` event  but before the function fires, I get a console message:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined"
```

`list_view.js.coffee`:

```
@GWA.module "QuestionsApp.List", (List, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

class List.Layout extends App.Views.Layout
    template: "questions/list/templates/question_layout"
    
    regions:
        optionRegion: "#option-region"
        questionRegion: "#question-region"

class List.Panel extends App.Views.ItemView
    template: "questions/list/templates/_question_panel"

class List.Question extends App.Views.ItemView
    template: "questions/list/templates/_question"

    onShow: (view) ->
        $(".slidetrack-survey").slider
            min: 0
            max: 100
            value: 50
            create: ->
                id = $(this).attr("id").replace("survey-slider-", "")
            change: ->
                $(this).addClass "moved"

    triggers:
        'slidechange .slidetrack' : (e, attrs) -> 
            App.execute "question:response", e, attrs.model

class List.Empty extends App.Views.ItemView
    template: "questions/list/templates/_empty"

class List.Questions extends App.Views.CompositeView
    template: "questions/list/templates/_questions"
    itemView: List.Question
    emptyView: List.Empty
```

`list_controller.js.coffee`:

```
@GWA.module "QuestionsApp.List", (List, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) -> 

class List.Controller extends Marionette.Controller
    
    initialize: ->
        questions =  App.request "question:entities", (questions) => 
            App.execute "when:fetched", questions, =>
                @layout = @getLayoutView questions
                @listenTo @layout, "change", @listQuestions questions
                @listenTo @layout, 'show', => 
                    @questionRegion()

    questionRegion: (questions) ->
        questionView = @getQuestionsView questions
        @listenTo questionView, "question:response", (args) ->
            @handleSliderChange(args)

        @layout.questionRegion.show questionView

    handleSliderChange: (args) ->
        console.log args.view
        console.log args.model
        console.log args.collection

    listQuestions: (questions) -> 
        @layout = @getLayoutView()
        @layout.on "show", =>
            @showQuestions questions
        App.dashboardRegion.show @layout

    showQuestions: (questions) ->
        questionsView = @getQuestionsView questions
        @layout.questionRegion.show questionsView

    getQuestionsView: (questions) ->
        new List.Questions
            collection: questions

    getLayoutView: ->
        new List.Layout
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem most probably happens, because you try to do processing inside the trigger:

```
triggers:
    'slidechange .slidetrack' : (e, attrs) -> 
        App.execute "question:response", e, attrs.model
```

Triggers should just bubble event from view up to higher level, where some kind of controller can handle it. You actually don't bubble anything, but process the event immediately and that confuses Marionette.

For this case, it would be easiest to just use *events* hash and move logic to external function like this:

```
events:
    'slidechange .slidetrack' : 'onSlideChange'

onSlideChange: (e, attrs) -> 
    App.execute "question:response", e, attrs.model
```

Comment: Thanks @drax! I appreciate it. I'll vote this up as soon as I accrue the reputation points.